TipTap is having issues rendering nested tree structures with proper formatting (bold,italic)
I'm working on a project that involves a nested tree of inputs with a depth of 3, which is sent to a TipTap rich text editor. The issue I'm facing is that when I apply formatting such as italic or bold to an element, it works initially, but when I add a new item to the document, the formatting reverts to its original state. Although the items are rendered correctly, the markup (bold, italic, etc.) does not persist. I need help resolving this issue
i tried using chatgpt and still couldnt solve it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
